# EF Core Update with tracked objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I use ABP Framework and I am really struggling on an update issue. I use entity frmaework core.

I am gonna try to ba as clear as I can.

I have a category table which hosts category names and details of the category.

Then I am building an angular UI which allows to select categories and store them in an accomplishement object.

Then my goal is to store Accomplishement and categories.

I then created a table AccomplishementCategoryCustoms.

So my model is as below:

```
[Table("Accomplishments")]
public class Accomplishment : AuditedEntity 
{

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

   public List<AccomplishementCategoryCustom> Categories { get; set; }
}

[Table("AccomplishementCategoryCustoms")]
public class AccomplishementCategoryCustom : CreationAuditedEntity 
{


    public virtual int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category CategoryFk { get; set; }

    public virtual int? AccomplishmentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccomplishmentId")]
    public Accomplishment AccomplishmentFk { get; set; }

}
```

I do not have relations between categories and AccomplishementCategoryCustoms.

Then when I insert it works well.

When I update and add the include I have the error as below:

[image: With include]

When I update without include I have an error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AccomplishementCategoryCustoms' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

FInally the modelbuilder is as below:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AccomplishementCategoryCustoms",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                CreationTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                CreatorUserId = table.Column<long>(nullable: true),
                CategoryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                AccomplishmentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AccomplishementCategoryCustoms", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AccomplishementCategoryCustoms_Accomplishments_AccomplishmentId",
                    column: x => x.AccomplishmentId,
                    principalTable: "Accomplishments",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AccomplishementCategoryCustoms_Categories_CategoryId",
                    column: x => x.CategoryId,
                    principalTable: "Categories",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AccomplishementCategoryCustoms_AccomplishmentId",
            table: "AccomplishementCategoryCustoms",
            column: "AccomplishmentId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AccomplishementCategoryCustoms_CategoryId",
            table: "AccomplishementCategoryCustoms",
            column: "CategoryId");
    }
```

I hope it will be enough detailed to have the fix because I am struggled on it since a long time and can't sort it out.

Comment: looks like you getting two object out from ef core, accomplishment and updateEnitty, by default, ef will track all objects that been queried and modified, in your case, your accomplishement hasn't been modified but updateEntity is modified while they both share same id, that confused ef core, you can try to use AsNoTracking mehtod to retrieve accomplishment object, for more info about tracking vs no tracking, here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Thanks but if I am changing the accomplishment by adding a name. Will it work? Because my goal is to save the whole object with all the changes that will be done.

Comment: Please post the implementation you are using for `UpdateAsync`. I am assuming that what is being done is that the entity is being attached to the database context for the repository and then `SaveChangesAsync` is being called on it. The issue with doing this is that if you are attaching an object that was just returned from the query you performed prior, Entity Framework will have already started tracking that instance, so it will fail upon attempting to attach it again. The solution is to not attach it explicitly, and simply call `SaveChangesAsync` on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I tried with the following code:

```
  var accomplishment = _accomplishmentRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking().Where(a => 
  a.Id ==input.Id.Value)
  .Include(a => a.Categories)
  .FirstOrDefault();

  var updatedEntity =  ObjectMapper.Map(input, accomplishment);

   await _accomplishmentRepository.UpdateAsync(updatedEntity);
```

I don't have the error anymore 
It's updated well.

However, if I unselect one category custom in my ui and update, the row in the db should be removed.

Unfortunately the change is not reflected in the database. The row is not changeing.

Then I tried to attach and set up modified but I have the error below:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

I really don't see how I can sort it out.

Comment: So the error you are seeing is letting you know that you cannot simply attach a list of something to the context. Lists in Entity Framework are treated as a special form of navigation property, and not just data sitting on an object; as such, you need to specifically do something with each object in the list or use Entity Framework Core APIs to get a CollectionEntry representing that list of things.

Comment: Yes but what I understand is that if I update without tracking it works well. But EF doesn't see the changes and do not update the row if needs to be deleted. And if I update with tracking it says there is an arreor: The instance of entity type 'AccomplishementCategoryCustom' cannot be tracked... So what is the solution? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I found something on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48963653/4780847 Do you think it's related to? If it's the case why they did this change? How can I setup this new way to update entities?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, assuming `_dbContextProvider.GetDbContext(Abp.MultiTenancy.MultiTenancySides.Host)` returns the database context you are targeting, which I have inferred from your answer, you can use the following code to persist changes to an accomplishment, including adding or removing categories, assuming as well that `ObjectMapper.Map(input, accomplishment)` is what is making changes to the accomplishment received from the repository, using the input, also assuming that `ObjectMapper.Map(input, accomplishment)` returns an entity type.

```cs
async Task Update(CreateOrEditAccomplishmentsDto input)
{
    var context = _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext(Abp.MultiTenancy.MultiTenancySides.Host);
    context.Entry(ObjectMapper.Map(input, _accomplishmentRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == input.Id.Value).Include(a => a.Categories).FirstOrDefault())).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Technically, the `context.Entry(...).State = EntityState.Modified` part of that line is redundant, but I'm not sure as to the implementation of anything you have provided, so I'm accounting for the context not actually tracking the returned object from the call to `Map`.

If you are getting an exception due to the context already tracking an entity with the same value for `id`, then **remove** the following line.

```cs
context.Entry(ObjectMapper.Map(input, _accomplishmentRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == input.Id.Value).Include(a => a.Categories).FirstOrDefault())).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Afterwards, add the following line in it's place before the call to `SaveChangesAsync`.

```
ObjectMapper.Map(input, _accomplishmentRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == input.Id.Value).Include(a => a.Categories).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have the error: The instance of entity type 'AccomplishementCategoryCustom' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Comment: I have updated my answer; please try the fix I posted at the bottom.

Comment: I have the same error. I am going to save objects by objects and not the full object at one time. Beacause to be honest I don't see where is the issue..

Comment: Essentially, because the call to `GetDbContext` returns a context that is already tracking one of the categories it is being told to track, it throws an exception. This error could also arise if the `Categories` list contains multiple categories with the same value for `id`.

Comment: Without more information it will be difficult to help much more. The simplest solution would be to use a fresh context, and to check that there are not duplicate categories on the accomplishment, then call `context.Update` with that accomplishment, followed by a call to `SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: I checked in the change tracker and the id for each columns are different. The AccomplishmentId is the same for several rows and the CategoryId but the primary key is different for every categories

Comment: That could be the issue; if multiple categories are present, attaching the accomplishment may cause all the categories to be tracked as well, in the order they are found, so it fails upon finding a previously-tracked one, but at this point I am unsure. It seems there may be something else not evident from the code posted.